# Python game,something with wrong answerrs why is this like that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is my python game:

```
import random



print('H A N G M A N')
hidden_words = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
hidden_word = random.choice(hidden_words)
display = '-' * len(hidden_word)
used = []
i = 0
maxshit = 8
while i < maxshit and display != hidden_word:
    print()
    print(display)
    inp = input("Input a letter: ")
    if inp in used:
        print("No improvements")
        i += 1
    elif inp in hidden_word:
        new = ""
        used.append(inp)
        for i in range(len(hidden_word)):
            if inp == hidden_word[i]:
                new += inp
            else:
                new += display[i]
        display = new 
    else:
        print("No such letter in the word")
        i += 1
if i == maxshit:
    print("You are hanged!")
else:
    print("You survived!")




print()
print('Thanks for playing!')
print("We'll see how well you did in the next stage")
```

It works well when there is 8 wrong answers you lose and game print "You are hanged !",but if you answer is well you win and it prints "You survived" and if you print allredy printed word it prints "No improvments!" or if there is no word what you inputed it prints "No such letter in the world !".
But when you input looks like

```
$ python govno.py
H A N G M A N

------
Input a letter: j
No such letter in the word

------
Input a letter: i

----i-
Input a letter: g
No such letter in the word

----i-
Input a letter: g
No such letter in the word

----i-
Input a letter: k

k---i-
Input a letter: g
No such letter in the word

k---i-
Input a letter: g
No such letter in the word

k---i-
Input a letter: g
No such letter in the word
You are hanged!
```

In this input you lose only after 6 mistakes. Why is this like that?
P.S sorry for comon mistakes I am only begining

Comment: wait what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your second loop (the for loop) you reused the variable `i`. When the input is in the hidden word and after the loop the variable `i` will be set to one less than the length of the hidden word ("kotlin"), which in this case is 5. After that, the `i` was incremented 3 times, ending at the value of 8, which is equal to `maxshit`. So the loop ended and the message was displayed.

Change that variable to another name (e.g. `j`).
The loop should look something like this:

```
        for j in range(len(hidden_word)):
            if inp == hidden_word[j]:
                new += inp
            else:
                new += display[j]
```